# if statement containing not in

Tags: python, string, if-statement

This if statement works...when I'm only looking for one string

```
    body = json.dumps(work['Body'])[2:-2]
    if len(something) >= 1 and 'SMILE' in body:
           print " i'm happy"
```

But this one does not when i'm looking for multiple strings....

```
    body = json.dumps(work['Body'])[2:-2]
    if len(something) >= 1 and 'SMILE' or 'LAUGH' or 'LOVE' or 'CHEER' in body:
           print " i'm still happy "
```

What gives?
How can I have multiple string in the if condition to match against another string?

Comment: `or` isn't a conjunction in Python; it's a boolean operator. It doesn't do anywhere near the amount of stuff the English conjunction "or" does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming body is some string, you can do as follows using [any](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any):

```
# for example
body='SMILE_LAUGH_SOMESTRING_WHTATEVER'
if len(something) >= 1 and any(s in body for s in ('SMILE', 'LAUGH', 'LOVE', 'CHEER')):
     print("i'm still happy")
```

Comment: what would be the opposite... so that i want to say "not in"... i want to have another if statement that says do xyz if those keywords are not in the string?

Comment: You could use [all](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#all) also. Or `not all(...)` or any combination depending what you want.

Comment: @user3467359 `and not any(` would be the opposite